# Put the Scroll View under the Up and Down Button

Tags: android, button, scrollview, updown

I want to show the scrollView under the Up and Down button as show in picture. And after taping on up and down arrow scroll bar should be scroll and after long press on the up and down button it should be scrolled continue till the end point.
Please tell me how we can Implement this.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perform `ScrollView .pageScroll()` or `ScrollView.smoothScrollBy()` on the tap event of the button.

Use a Runnable to continues invoke `ScrollView.scrollBy()` when long press event happens. I wrote a demo for you.

```
public class TestAndroidActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,
        OnGestureListener {
    private static final String TAG = "TestAndroid";
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private ScrollView mScrollView;
    private Button mBtnUp;
    private Button mBtnDown;
    private View mCurBtn;
    private GestureDetector mDetecor;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        mBtnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_up);
        mBtnDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_down);
        mBtnUp.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mBtnDown.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mDetecor = new GestureDetector(this, this);
    }

    private long mStartTime = 0;
    private float mSpeed = 0.5f;
    private Runnable mScrollRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int dy = (int) ((SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStartTime) * mSpeed);
            mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            int direction = getCurrentBtnDirection();
            if (direction == View.FOCUS_UP)
                dy *= -1;
            mScrollView.scrollBy(0, dy);
            mHandler.post(this);
        }
    };

    private int getCurrentBtnDirection() {
        if (mCurBtn == mBtnUp) {
            return View.FOCUS_UP;
        } else if (mCurBtn == mBtnDown) {
            return View.FOCUS_DOWN;
        } else
            return 0;
    }

    private void perfromPageScroll() {
        int direction = getCurrentBtnDirection();
        mScrollView.pageScroll(direction);
    }

    private void stopContinuousScroll() {
        mStartTime = 0;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mScrollRunnable);
    }

    private void startContinuousScroll() {
        mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        mHandler.post(mScrollRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mCurBtn = v;
        mDetecor.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            stopContinuousScroll();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        perfromPageScroll();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        startContinuousScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

If you want to detect the scroll state of the ScrollView to enable or disable the buttons, you must write a CustomView to extends ScrollView and override the OnScrollChanged() method.

**EDIT:** add the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="1\n\n\n\n\n\n2\n\n\n\n\n\n3\n\n\n\n\n4\n\n\n\n5\n\n"
            android:textSize="32sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="up" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="down" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT2:** If you are using a ListView, you can use `ListView.smoothScrollBy()` to replace `ScrollView.scrollBy()`. There is not a pageScroll() method in ListView, write it by yourself, it's not very hard.

**EDIT3:** pageScroll for ListView

```
private void pageScroll(ListView l) {
    l.smoothScrollBy(l.getHeight(), 300);
}
```

Comment: I cannot believe such a detailed sample doesn't deserve any feedback.

Comment: I didn't try this, Bcz am trying to implement all those things which I asked.

Comment: How do you know that i did not implement all your requirements even without trying the demo.

Comment: I implement the scroll bar in listview between both up and down arrow buttons. Which is not implement in your code.

Comment: You said that 'show the scrollView under the Up and Down', it's just a RelativeLayout with a ScrollView and two Buttons. I thought you have already wrote the layout.

Comment: But Scrollview is related with listview

Comment: You described two layouts. 1. Show the scrollView under the Up and Down, this is just a RelativeLayout. 2. Show the Buttons inside the listview, but the scrollBar should be shown between the two buttons. This is really hard and a different question. The code to draw ScrolBar is in View.class and is not easy to modify. Maybe you should draw the scrollBar by yourself to solve the problem.

Comment: Okay, I just trying this. Making a Listview and show the scrollBar of that listview under the Up and Down Button.

Comment: If you are just trying to acieve 'under' but not 'between', what's the problem with my layout that using a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Okay, Please don't misunderstood. I want to the Listview with scroll bar which view is just as the given image...!!!

Comment: Orz... you totally defeat me.

Comment: Please tell me how I can write own pageScroll() method for listview?

Comment: pageScroll for listview is added.

Answer (score 0):

For going to Top you can use the method

```
ScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP)
```

For scrolling portions.. basically you can use the function

```
ScrollView.smoothScrollTo (int x, int y)
```

You can get the current `X, Y` positions by `getScrollX()` and `getScrollY()` and then add some amount to scroll further.

Comment: But it is not a complete answer.