# How to make ScrollView scroll while button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-button, android-scrollview

my problem is quite simple actually, I couldn't find a way to do what's mentionned in my question. I tried with AsyncTask, which didn't work at all, also with the OnFocusChange event of the button... I'm a bit desperate at now.

Hope you guys could help ! :)

**AsyncTask Version :**

```
private void creationVoid(){
    (...)
    btScrollDown.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                downPressed = true;
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                downPressed = false;
            new ScrollDownTask().execute();
            return true;
        }
    });
(...)
}


private void scrollDown(){
    btScrollUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    scrollView.scrollTo(scrollView.getScrollX(), scrollView.getScrollY() + 15);
    if(scrollView.getScrollY() == scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount()-1).getBottom() - 763) {
        btScrollDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private class ScrollDownTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {return null;}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        while(downPressed)
            scrollDown();
    }
}
```

**OnFocusChange Version :**

```
private void creationVoid(){
    (...)
    btScrollDown.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            while(hasFocus)
                scrollDown();
        }
    });
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Please add your code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Added some code ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the button is pressed, you can call the `smoothScrollBy` or the `smoothScrollTo` method. You have to, however,based on your requirement  calculate how much to scroll the view. Hope this helps.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy(int,%20int)

Comment: I don't know because I need to scroll repeatedly, which is the main problem, but this helps for another purposes thanks for sharing !

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737754/put-the-scroll-view-under-the-up-and-down-button. Seems very close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach.

- Start a timer when you press the button and cancel the timer when you lift the touch from the button
- On the timer fired method, scroll by a certain value (y).

Fine tune the timer interval and the scrollBy value y to suite your requirement.