# Custom Scrollbar for TextView in Android

Tags: android, scrollbar

How can one achieve scrollbar like one below for TextView?

So what i mean is, the scrollbar style is custom and is visible when the content does not fit into TextView.

[image]

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: add this android:scrollbars = "vertical" to textview

Comment: have you tried the suggestions from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171755/custom-scrollbar-android

Comment: Hi i have tried that, i can get the standard scrollbar but unsure of how to get buttons for scroll up and scroll down

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `ScrollView` to a `TextView`. You can make it scrollable instead (which is technically same)

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/6155248) , hope you get your solution!

Comment: @Tamid thanks for that however what i actually want is the way it looks.

Comment: you want it appear all the time beside textview or when it should be scrolled?

Comment: Appear when the content cant be fitted in the text view.

Comment: ok think i got your point ; you want to make `TextView` scrollable and at the same time, the scroll should have your custom style... am i right?

Comment: so, for the first step(scrollable `TextView`) you could follow my answer above and for the second step (styling scrollbar) you can go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14487645/6155248)

Comment: Thanks for the link, i have had look at the link, however it still doesn't answer how i can add scroll up / scroll down button like the one in image

Comment: let me have a minute to check please

Comment: till now i could find the closest solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738850/6155248) , but i will let you know if I can figure out any better way.. (sorry for the delay)